# SQL Server trigger to replace "false" with null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a table with 2 `numeric` columns and 3 `varchar` columns in a SQL Server 2017 database. I want a trigger to check each inserted/updated row and when any of the `varchar` columns contain the text "false", replace it with `NULL`.

There is no primary key column and every column is null-able, so I won't be able to join with the "inserted" pseudo table.

I am more familiar with Oracle where the logic for this could be something like:

```
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF new.TEXT_COLUMN1 = 'false' THEN new.TEXT_COLUMN1 := null; END IF;
  IF new.TEXT_COLUMN1 = 'false' THEN new.TEXT_COLUMN1 := null; END IF;
  IF new.TEXT_COLUMN1 = 'false' THEN new.TEXT_COLUMN1 := null; END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this without a primary key. You are working on a database that is missing primary keys and you need to resort to triggers to implement your logic - red flags everywhere! If the table is not very big you could just add a blanket update in the trigger (which will cause performance impacts as the table grows). If the value doesn't need to be immediately updated, you run a scheduled job that does a blanket update. Both of these solutions are bad but only because you have a bad situation to start with

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did a variation of the solution suggested by Josh and it worked out (albeit requires changes when table schema changes). It is definitely unfortunate that the table has no primary key(s), but alas this is a sort of OLAP data-dump table with different sources having different keys (so each key must be nullable) and they didn't create any synthetic key because it was easy for them to live without one in Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is an *INSTEAD OF* trigger.  The general idea is that it will intercept your insert, and won't actually insert any rows at all... Unless you tell it to.

And when you tell it to, you can do the replacements.  To actually insert rows, just use some insert statements inside your *INSTEAD OF* trigger.  Don't worry, it won't be recursive.

```
create trigger ReplaceFalseTrigger on table1 instead of insert as

insert into table1 (TEXT_COLUMN1) 
       select 
           case when TEXT_COLUMN1='false' then null else TEXT_COLUMN1 end
       from inserted;
```

That's the gist of it anyway.  I'll leave it to you to add in all your other mystery columns.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more like this:

```
update t  -- table being inserted into
     set TEXT_COLUMN1 = null
     from inserted i join
          t
          on t.id = i.id
     where t.TEXT_COLUMN1 = 'false';
```

Comment: The problem here is that there is no t.id column to join to (this table has no primary key and I am unable to add one)